# Facebook iframe application form redirect

Tags: facebook, iframe, redirect, facebook-php-sdk

I posted some of this a bit ago.

The problem is that my form inside the iframe application is redirecting away from facebook,
also i put a target="_top" to it.

```
<form action="http://xample.com/index.php" method="post" target="_top">
```

also i think it is a common question i found no result on stackoverflow or with the help of google.

maybe someone has a lmgtfy link ;)

thx sven

Comment: [Try this link.](http://www.takwing.idv.hk/tech/fb_dev/faq/iframe_app/iframe_08.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just to simple.

```
<form action="http://xample.com/index.php" method="post" target="iframe_canvas">
```

Comment: I have already done that but it's opening a new browser's tab :(